# GoLang простая функция для работы с запросами Postregsql

Tags: postgresql, golang

Пытаюсь написать процедуру, которая одной строчкой будет делать `prepare` и `exec/query`:

```
package postregsql

import (
    "database/sql"
    "errors"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func Query(database *sql.DB, sql string, args ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error) {

    db_stmt, err := database.Prepare(sql)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Ошибка Query(" + sql + ")<DB_Prepare>: " + err.Error())
    }

    defer db_stmt.Close()

    db_rows, err := db_stmt.Query(args...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Ошибка Query(" + sql + ")<DB_Query>: " + err.Error())
    }

    defer db_rows.Close()

    return db_rows, nil
}

func Exec(database *sql.DB, sql string, args ...interface{}) error {

    db_stmt, err := database.Prepare(sql)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("Ошибка Exec(" + sql + ")<DB_Prepare>: " + err.Error())
    }

    defer db_stmt.Close()

    _, err = db_stmt.Exec(args...)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("Ошибка Exec(" + sql + ")<DB_Exec>: " + err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}
```

> Exec() для INSERT/UPDATE/CREATE
>
> Query() для SELECT

`Exec()` справляется со своей задачей отлично, вот с `Query()` проблема - на любой запрос с аргументами выдает пустые ответы, например:

```
name := "1"
answer, _ := postregsql.Query(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE name=$1;", name)
count := 0
for answer.Next {
   answer.Scan(&count)
}

// count == 0 (по факту больше 1 должно быть)
```

Грешу на эту строчку `*db_rows, err := db_stmt.Query(args...)*` - как ее исправить, чтобы работало корректно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

defer db_rows.Close() выполняется раньше, чем начинаешь обрабатывать результаты answer.Next, answer.Scan(), сразу, как покидаешь функцию Query().

Не понятен смысл этой функции, есть же database.Query().

Comment: сократить количество строчек, чтобы постоянно не вызывать сначала prepare, затем query.

Comment: Так можно же без db.Prepare() и потом stmt.Query() вызывать сразу db.Query().

Comment: мне кажется db.Prepare() подготавливает безопасный/экранированный от инъекций запрос. если я не прав, то поправьте меня, пожалуйста

Comment: Запросы готовятся одинаково, что в db.Prepare(), что в db.Query().